# What happens when a variable is set private?

Tags: encapsulation

What really happens when you set a variable to private? 
I mean, how does the compiler prevent a user from accessing the contents of a private variable?

Comment: by giving compiler error? If you are asking about how all implementation is done in the compiler itself, its probably too broad a topic to explain properly here.

Comment: Yeah, I did mean how we implement this functionality in the compiler itself. If you don't mind could you guide me to a few resources that you might have in mind?